# Customized Calendar view using @fullcalendar/react NPM package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar, timeline, gantt-chart

I need to integrate the calendar view in react application which will show the activities and under each activity we will have multiple tasks. I am attaching the screenshot of my requirement. Can you please help me to know is this feasible or not.

Following are some main points that I need to achieve:

1. Show three months of activities and tasks.
2. Parent level activities should have expand/collapse functionality.
3. User should be able to scroll the view horizontally.

I have tried the free version of [@fullcalendar/react](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-react). But I am not able to achieve the above mentioned points. I am ready to buy the premium version of it if all my requirements are met.

```js
<FullCalendar
stickyFooterScrollbar={true}
dayMinWidth={150}
ref={calendarRef}
schedulerLicenseKey='CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives'
plugins={[
  interactionPlugin,
  resourceTimelinePlugin,
  dayGridPlugin,
  multiMonthPlugin,
  scrollgridPlugin,
  timelinePlugin
  // timeGridPlugin,
]}
headerToolbar={{
  left: 'today,prev,next',
  center: '',
  right: '',
  // 'next,customWeeks,dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,resourceTimelineWeek',
}}
initialView='customWeeks'
// slotMinWidth={'100px'}
filterResourcesWithEvents={true}
selectOverlap={true}
slotEventOverlap={true}
eventOverlap={false}
views={{
  customWeeks: {
    eventOverlap: false,
    type: 'timelineWeek',
    duration: { months: 3 },
    slotDuration: { days: 7 },
    dateIncrement: { months: 3 },
    buttonText: 'Custom Week',
    slotMinWidth: 70,
  },
}}
events={events}
resourceAreaWidth='160px'
weekNumbers={true}
resourceAreaHeaderContent=' '
display_mode={{
  tooltip: true,
}}
resources={resources}
editable={true}
selectable={true}
selectMirror={true}
dayMaxEvents={true}
weekends={calendarState.weekendsVisible}
allDaySlot={false}
eventDidMount={EventDetail1} />
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

[image]

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253914/discussion-on-question-by-shubham-customized-calendar-view-using-fullcalendar-r); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: How can I show the events b/w two dates in fullCalendar.

Comment: See the comment above? Where it says **please do not continue the discussion here**...? Did you read it? Tag me in the chat if you want to ask something. But if you have a new issue, it's better to post a new question usually. Only use the chat if it's a genuine continuation of your existing issue. Also it's unclear what specificall `show the events b/w two dates in fullCalendar` actually mean in practice anyway. You'd need to give proper examples.